# send data from server to an OSX app

Tags: swift, macos

I am building an OSX app that needs to get data from server. The easy way, is to make a GET request at some fixed time interval, and process results. Thats not what I want. I want the other way around: e.g. server to send data to my app, when something happens on the server side. That way I do not need to make constant requests from client side. I don't need the data to visually be displayed, just processed.

Can this be implemented in OSX with Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to achieve this:

**Websocket:**

[Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a full-duplex communication channel over a TCP-Connection. It's established via HTTP.

**Long Polling:**

Same as you said before but without responding directly. Your client makes a HTTP request and set a very long timeout timer. The server responds after something is happening. ([More](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/))

I would recommend you Websocket since it was built exactly for this use case. But if you have to implement it quickly you should probably go with long polling for now, since the barrier to implement it is much lower and switch to Websocket later.